# RuntimeException on cursor.getCount()

Tags: android, sqlite

Fabric reported me this error, so I really don't know when and how it could be caused. Maybe the user stopped the application while accessing the DB...

The code is:

```
private void addOrUpdateJoinTable(SQLiteDatabase db, long site_id, JSONArray myJSONCategoriesArray) throws JSONException {

    ContentValues newCategoriesValues = new ContentValues();
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < myJSONCategoriesArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsCategory = myJSONCategoriesArray.getJSONObject(i);

            cursor = db.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT " +
                            SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_SITES_CATEGORIES_TABLE + "." + SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_ID +  ", " +
                            SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_SITES_TABLE + "." + SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " AS S_id, " +
                            SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_CATEGORIES_TABLE + "." + SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " AS C_id " +
                            " FROM " +
                            SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_SITES_TABLE +
                            " INNER JOIN " +
                            SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_SITES_CATEGORIES_TABLE + " ON " +
                            SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_SITES_CATEGORIES_TABLE + "." + SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_SITE_ID + " = S_id " +
                            " INNER JOIN " +
                            SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_CATEGORIES_TABLE + " ON " +
                            "C_id = " +
                            SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_SITES_CATEGORIES_TABLE + "." + SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_CATEGORY_ID +
                            " WHERE " +
                            "S_id = ?" +
                            " AND " +
                            SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_CATEGORIES_TABLE + "." + SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_CODE + " = ?",
                    new String[] {Long.toString(site_id), jsCategory.get(SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_CODE).toString()}
            );


            if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {

                cursor.moveToFirst();

                long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_ID));

                newCategoriesValues.put(SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_SITE_ID, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("S_id")));
                newCategoriesValues.put(SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_CATEGORY_ID, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("C_id")));

                result = db.update(SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_SITES_CATEGORIES_TABLE, newCategoriesValues, SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{Long.toString(id)});

                if (debug) Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "update " + newCategoriesValues.toString());
            } else {

                String resultSites_columns[] = new String[] {
                        SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_ID,
                        SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_CODE,
                };

                String where = SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_CODE
                        + " = ?";

                String whereArgs[] = {jsCategory.get(SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_CODE).toString()};

                cursor = db.query(SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_CATEGORIES_TABLE, resultSites_columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);

                if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {

                    //dumpCursor(cursor);

                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    newCategoriesValues.put(SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_SITE_ID, site_id);

                    newCategoriesValues.put(SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_CATEGORY_ID, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_ID)));

                    db.insert(SitesDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_SITES_CATEGORIES_TABLE, null, newCategoriesValues);

                    if (debug) Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "insert " + newCategoriesValues.toString());
                } else {

                    if (debug) Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "!! category not found !! " + jsCategory.get(SitesDBOpenHelper.KEY_CODE).toString());

                }

            }
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        if (debug) Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "NumberFormatException " + e);
    }catch (SQLiteException e) {
        if (debug) Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG, "SQLLiteException " + e);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=649 (# cursors opened by this proc=649)
       at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:108)
       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
       at com.my.example.LoadSitesListTask.addOrUpdateJoinTable(LoadSitesListTask.java:1461)
       at com.my.example.LoadSitesListTask.updateDBFromJSONData(LoadSitesListTask.java:1152)
       at com.my.example.LoadSitesListTask.doInBackground(LoadSitesListTask.java:153)
       at com.my.example.LoadSitesListTask.doInBackground(LoadSitesListTask.java:58)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Could anyone tell me something on such kind of error? 
Is it "normal" if the user stopped the app while working? or is it possible to prevent such cases?

One strange thing anyway is the allocation of 2048 kb requested for the cursor.
You can see that based on the `resultSites_columns` containing 2 integers, 2048 kb doesn't make sense.

Does it mean something?

Comment: Are you sure you close the cursor?

Comment: @user yes I am, this excerpt is in a big try/catch and the cursor is closed in the `finally`. And this crash is first occurence I've ever seen.

Comment: did you write cursor.moveToFirst();   ?

Comment: I think you need to post the whole block, having 649 cursors open means that the are definitely not getting closed.

Comment: @Godwin, later yes but not before the line where the code crashes.

Comment: @Malcolm, Ok, I added the whole code, what you say is really strange, I didn't know it was the coursor count. VERY interesting. I'm going to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that cursors are not getting closed. You have a loop inside the try-finally block, but issue is that you open `myJSONCategoriesArray.length()` cursors, but you close only the last one, the one that was assigned to `cursor` in the last iteration of the loop.

What you need to do is move the try-finally block inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myJSONCategoriesArray.length(); i++) {
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(/* rest omitted */);
    try {
        // Use the cursor
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) cursor.close();
    }
}
```

That way you will close all the cursors and not just the last one.